# ExecuteAsyncGet RestSharp doesn't end when webservice IS returning JSON

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am using the library RestSharp and i have the following method to retrieve a `Venue` model. The situation I am facing is very strange. The method I use looks like this:

```
public void GetCurrentVenue (Action<Venue> callback)
    {

        var client = new RestClient (String.Format("{0}/api/v1", Constants.Base_Url));
        var request = new RestRequest (String.Format("venues/current"));
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json; 

        client.ExecuteAsyncGet<Venue> (request, (IRestResponse<Venue> arg1, RestRequestAsyncHandle arg2) => {
            callback (arg1.Data);
        }, "GET");

    }
```

I am invoking the method in the following way:

```
protected void ObtainCurrentVenue() {

        new DAL.Services.ServiceFactory ().createVenueService ().GetCurrentVenue ((Venue venue) =>  {

            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(HomeScreen));

            if(venue.ID != 0) {
                new BL.Managers.VenueManager().SaveVenue(venue);
                intent.PutExtra("venue_id", venue.ID.ToString());
            } else {
                intent.PutExtra("venue_id", 0.ToString());
            }

            StartActivity(intent);

        });



    }
```

Ok, so I have a couple of scenarios which I will describe. First scenario:

- Executing the `GetCurrentVenue()` method while I am aren't on a current venue. This will produce an empty `Venue` model by my webservice. With the above `GetCurrentVenue()` method it is returning the empty model just fine.
- Executing the `GetCurrentVenue()` method while I **am** on a current venue. This will produce JSON that fills my model and this is where i have a problem. My `callback()` will never be called while executing this in an async way.

The strangest part of all is that when i change my method to the following:

```
public void GetCurrentVenue (Action<Venue> callback)
        {

            var client = new RestClient (String.Format("{0}/api/v1", Constants.Base_Url));
            var request = new RestRequest (String.Format("venues/current"));
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json; 

            var response = client.ExecuteAsGet<Venue>(request);

            callback (response.Data);

        }
```

The `GetCurrentVenue()` DOES work in both scenarios. So now it is executing on the main a.k.a the UI thread. When I use the Async variant, it is producing the following in my application log:

```
Thread started:  #2
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #3
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #4
```

And some lines below that:

```
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #5
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #6
```

The application is now waiting for something to finish and I can't debug the code in the Async variant of the `GetCurrentVenue()` because it never reaches the `callback()`. Does somebody know what is going on?

Comment: Are you sure the callback isn't called. It could be called outside the UI thread and crash. This does not always give an error. Put some Console.Writeline statements in to be sure.